# Setting local PyCharm remote interpreter in docker container on remote server

Tags: python, docker, ssh, pycharm

I have:

1. local PyCharm
2. remote server with docker container

I want run in my local PyCharm code (code on remote server) in remote docker container Python interpreter, for debug.
How to set it up?

I also found articles on the Internet, with the following description that I did not need:

1. local PyCharm -> ssh server interpreter
2. local PyCharm -> local docker

Comment: What's wrong with ssh apporach?  You'd have to ssh to the container. How is the code run in the container? Do you have access to the shell that runs python code?

Comment: @RafalS i do **0.** `ssh user@host`, **1.** `docker build build_file`, **2.** `docker run run_file`, **3.** `docker exec -it {short_hash_image} bash`, **4.** `python3 ex.py`.


And (4.), run in docker container.


_Maybe I did something wrong in the description._

Answer (score 0):

While it's not impossible to connect pycharm debugger with your remote docker container, it's much easier to use terminal interactive debugger - [pdb](https://realpython.com/python-debugging-pdb/). There are a lot of pdb flavours, if you don't like plain console

- [webpdb](https://pypi.org/project/web-pdb/) graphical debugger in a browser
- [pudb](https://pypi.org/project/pudb/) ncurses version, has some extra features like always listing your location in code and local variables.

I highly recommend checking them out. I use pdb on daily basis to debug python code in local docker container that has a complex run script.